# Create local named ranges named as the header in a table using a VBA button in excel

Tags: excel, vba

There's this VBA button at work (VBA is password protected sadly) that I'm been trying to replicate. It is called something like "name range with top".

You select a cell anywhere in a table and click the button and for each column in the table it creates a local named range (ie local to the sheet as opposed to a global named range covering the whole spreadsheet) with the name of the top cell of each column, ie the column header.

From watching what happens in the sheet after the button is pressed it looks to work by first selecting the whole of the table and then going column-by-column, selecting the whole of each column working its way across the table.

So given the table:
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJNow.png)

If I selected any cell within B3:E8 and pressed the button it would create the named ranges: "Year", "Sales", "Profit", "Loss" which would cover B4:B8, C4:C8, D4:D8 & E4:E8 respectively.

You get errors if there are spaces in the value in a header or in the name of the sheet - which seems to be the usual requirements of a named range to have no spaces in its names.

So far I think I've got the "create named range based on the selected column" bit into VBA, but I can't figure out how to get it to select the whole of the table, then select the whole of each column in turn and then to take the top value of the column as the name (and then exclude the top value from the named range):

```
Sub NamedRangeSelected()
     Dim RangeName As String
      
    'specify the name of the range
     RangeName = "Name"
   
    'create named range with workbook scope
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Selection

End Sub
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated as its such a useful tool for index matching, making formula so much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will not throw and error if the column caption contains a space. Instead, it will replace the space with an underscore. However, it may object to other invalid characters in the name.

```
Sub CreateColumnRanges()
    ' 278
    
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet            ' the sheet with the table
    Dim Tbl         As ListObject
    Dim RangeName   As String
    Dim NamedRange  As Name
    Dim C           As Long                 ' loop counter: columns
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet                    ' change to suit
    Set Tbl = Ws.ListObjects(1)             ' refer to the first table on Ws
    With Tbl.ListColumns
        For C = 1 To .Count
            ' replace spaces in the name with underscores
            ' (remove leading/trailing blanks)
            RangeName = Replace(Trim(.Item(C).Range.Cells(1).Value), " ", "_")
            Set NamedRange = Ws.Names.Add(Name:=RangeName, _
                             RefersTo:=Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(C))
            NamedRange.Comment = Tbl.Name & "[" & Replace(RangeName, "_", " ") & "]"
        Next C
    End With
End Sub
```

The code is independent of any selection you may make on the sheet or within the table. You can select it from the Macro menu on the Developer tab, run it on F5 from the VB Editor or hitch it to a button you add to your worksheet. Existing ranges by the same names will be replaced with the new specs without warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not working with ListObjects:

```vb
Sub MakeNames()
    Dim rng As Range, col, nm
    
    Set rng = Selection.CurrentRegion
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub 'check have a usable area...
    
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        nm = Replace(col.Cells(1), " ", "_")
        ActiveSheet.Parent.Names.Add Name:=nm, _
           RefersTo:=col.Offset(1).Resize(col.Cells.Count - 1)
    Next col
End Sub
```